# It is a question by the APN setting of NOKIA Lumia 635

Tags: settings, unlocking, lumia-635

Setting ＞ extra + information Manufacturer Name and Mobile Operator RM-975_1005 ATT-US

Is my lumia 635 locked?

In Japan a message saying that a network is not found is given.

Data connection is on I do not roam. When WiFi connection is limited, I use a mobile data network.

By setting of SIM, SIM name (choice of the NTTDOCOMO ****) network) NTTDOCOMO

Internet APN APN vmobile.jp User name dmm@dmm.com Password ＊＊Think that is known generally according to *(; a kind of the) certification PAP Proxy server Proxy port Blanks

MMS APN Kind of the certification PAP (grayout) Kind of the IP IPv4v6

I seem to recognize SIM and seem to catch the network of DOCOMO.

I bought unloked model in amazon US,I think.